# Nombre repetido en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo este código , lo que quiero es que no se pueda repetir el nombre y apellido, por ej si un usuario ingresa juan perez que luego no pueda volver a ingresar otra apuesta con el nombre juan perez, lo que hice yo esta mal pero me parece que viene por ahí la mano.

```
    bool repetidoo = false;
                    string nom,ape;
                    if (tope < nombres.Length)
                    {
                        repetidoo = false;
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                            Console.Write("INGRESE NOMBRE : ");
                            nom = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                            Console.Write("\n" + "INGRESE APELLIDO : ");
                            ape = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();
                            for (int j = 0; j <= nom.Length; j++)
                            {
                                if (nom == nombres[tope])
                                {
                                    repetidoo = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if (repetidoo)
                            {
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                                Console.WriteLine("Nombre repetido"); // 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                nombres[tope] = nom;
                            }
```

Comment: te recomiendo que investiges un poco sobre Linq y veras que usando Linq es muy facil y elegante.

Comment: @Francop si alguna de las respuestas ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta  (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo bastantes problemas en el código.

Si vas a añadir elementos a la lista de nombres, es decir no va a tener una longitud fija, deberías utilizar mejor una lista genérica en lugar de un array.

Recoges el nombre y el apellido pero únicamente almacenas y comparas el nombre.

Si el usuario va a tener diferentes propiedades (como nombre y apellido) que vas a tratar por separado lo mejor sería que te crearas una clase o estructura para encapsular la información del usuario.

Si vas a mostrar los mensajes en rojo lo mejor sería que te crearas un método que lo hiciera, de forma que, si en un futuro quieres cambiar el formato de los mensajes de error, únicamente deberías cambiarlo en un sitio.

Deberías comprobar también que el usuario no introduzca un nombre o apellido (o ambos) vacíos.

Échale un vistazo a este ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Console_CSharp
{
    class Program
    {

        public class Persona
        {
            public Persona(string nombre, string apellido)
            {
                Nombre = nombre;
                Apellido = apellido;
            }

            public string Nombre { get; }
            public string Apellido { get; }
        }

        private const int TopePersonas = 10;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var personas = new List<Persona>();
            while (ObtenerOpcion()!='X')
            {
                NuevaPersona(personas);
            }

            Console.Write("\n\n--------------------\n");
            Console.Write("Personas introducidas\n\n");
            foreach (var persona in personas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{persona.Nombre} {persona.Apellido}");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static char ObtenerOpcion()
        {
            Console.Write("\n\n--------------------\n");
            Console.WriteLine("(1) Introducir nombre");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("(X) Salir");
            ConsoleKeyInfo c;
            Console.Write("--------------------\n");
            do
            {
                c = Console.ReadKey();
            } while (c.KeyChar != '1' && c.KeyChar != 'x' && c.KeyChar != 'X');
            Console.WriteLine();
            return c.KeyChar == 'x' ? 'X' : c.KeyChar;
        }

        private static void MostrarError(string error)
        {
            var previousColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(error);
            Console.ForegroundColor = previousColor;
        }

        private static string SolicitarCadena(string mensaje)
        {
            var previousColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.Write($"{mensaje}: ");
            var cadena = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim();
            Console.ForegroundColor = previousColor;
            return cadena;
        }

        private static void NuevaPersona(List<Persona> personas)
        {
            if (TopePersonas <= personas.Count)
            {
                MostrarError("Se ha llegado al tope");
                return;
            }

            var nom = SolicitarCadena("Ingrese Nombre");
            var apellido = SolicitarCadena("Ingrese apellido");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nom) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(apellido))
            {
                MostrarError("Debe introducir ambos valores");
                return;
            }

            if (personas.Any(p => string.Equals(p.Nombre, nom, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
                    && string.Equals(p.Apellido, apellido, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
            {
                MostrarError($"Ya se ha introducido una persona con el nombre {nom} {apellido}");
                return;
            }

            personas.Add(new Persona(nom, apellido));
        }
    }
}
```

Es completamente funcional. Puedes probarlo.

El método `NuevaPersona` es el que contiene la funcionalidad de tu ejemplo. Utiliza dos métodos: `MostrarError` y `SolicitarCadena` para mostrar los mensajes de error y pedir la introducción de datos respectivamente.